# Mac mode where you can see code on startup

Tags: mac, unix

In *The Outliers*, Bill Joy is quoted as saying

> "If you put your Mac in that funny mode where you can see the code, I
>   see things that I can remember typing 25 years ago."

I'm intrigued - what is this mode? How does one use it?

Comment: What Mac? What OS? It might be [MacsBug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacsBug) and the programmer switch on the old 68000 original Mac line, but it's hard to tell without more clarity.

Comment: @2xedo Unix is the Mac OS "core". And it is Linux's too. If you're interested in seeing what a Unix code might looks like, you can do it through Linux: in Linux you can download (and eventually edit and publish your own distro) the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single user or Verbose mode.

### Verbose mode start up

- Restart the Mac
- Immediately hold down the command + V keys

You have successfully entered verbose mode when you see white text appear on the screen.

See [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573)

Comment: I think this is what was being referred to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing (from the user point-of-view). Mac OS X is not an open-source operating system.

Comment: Must have been a developer tool, then?

Comment: If you're a developer and you work in Cupertino, sure!

Comment: Or is it referring to Terminal? Lol.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, He is talking about single user mode. Single user mode is a state of the operating system used to repair functionality of the operating system.

Comment: Coding was done on the black screen which still exists under all that GUI.  You can see that it starting up in Verbose Mode - which is also the way to get out of  kernel panic. Hold down Comm-V.

Comment: @Zo219 Yes, either verbose or single user mode. The output seems as if it is the "code". Enough speculating.